# SSIS: How can I set variables based on data in a text file?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a text file with 5 columns and a variable amount of rows.  What would be the easiest way to grab the first row of the text file and set 5 different variables in SSIS to the values of the 5 columns in the first row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Define your **five variables** in the package, and **one more** for row_count.
- Setup a **Flat File Source**.
- Use **Row Count** component to count rows.
- Use **Conditional Split** on row_count == 1.
- Use **Script Component** to capture row data into variables.